# Why is my Arabic writing broken?

Tags: fonts, lyx, arabic, dvi

Previously, I tested LyX for writing in Arabic with the Arabic (Arabi) language setting. LyX could render Arabic writing properly at that time without punctuation or harakat. But, if I add harakat or punctuation, it becomes like this: (in this case, writing "بِسْمِ اللَّهِ")

[image: Broken Arabic writing]

The harakat and letters become separated or disjointed, so rather than "بِسْمِ اللَّهِ", the DVI renders it to "بـ ِ س ْ م ِ  اللـ َّهـ" instead. What's the solution for this problem?

I use Almohanad font on this time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There's a good chance it's a bug in LyX, but we do not have an Arabic-speaker on the development team so it is hard for us to fix these bugs. In your posts, it's very important if you could please give minimal examples. Please read here and edit in your .lyx file into the question: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: I haven't used LyX for a while, but have you tried the PDF output with the XeTeX engine instead?

Comment: Yes, it works. Alhamdulillah.